# Cryptanalyze strategy for cipher text

Tags: cryptanalysis, classical-cipher

I have the following ciphertext that I want to decipher:

> bnmkogt vgyhni uioopkm xswercvdf yuiogvbnm ghjy cftyhng tgeyjn
>   xdrtygvc zsefx xdrgbhu tgbnmko tgbnmhyui yhnmko vbnmgyuiok

So far, what I have done:

- Perform a frequency analysis. This suggests that no transposition cipher was used. I Also try all 26 ROT combinations for substitution cipher with no results.
- Move to polyalphabetic ciphers. My first option is Vigenere. In that context I found that there are several trigrams , **bnm**, repeated and two 5-grams, **bnmko**, (which is probably not random and indicates that the same text is encrypted with the same part of the key).
- I use the only 4-letter-word of the text, GHJY, and compare it with the most common four-letter words in English (assuming it is English...), with no good results.
- I measure the distance between the 5-grams and found that is 72, which factors are 1,2,3,4,6,8,9,12,18,24,36.
- I also ran an Index of Coincidence analysis which suggests that the key length is 7.

I think that I'm missing something. Any thoughts/ideas on how can I better address this cryptogram? What would you do?
Thanks!

PS. The only clue of the cryptogram says "Manual work". Apparently, it is a classic cipher...

[image]

Comment: Are you sure about the distance of the 5-grams? You need to compare the start of each 5-grams, without spaces!

Comment: I have removed the spaces when I did the distance count (72), but did not start in the beginning of the 5-gram (I did it at the end). Then the distance is 77, which factors are only 7 and 11. Being 7 the number I got in the Coincidence Analysis!. Excellent observation @MaartenBodewes!

Comment: Still unable to crack it. Ideas?

Comment: Well, there are likely only $7 \cdot log_2(26) \approx 7 \cdot 4.7 \approx 33$ bits of key space, so you could try and brute force it. But you should probably assume Vigenère and just trying keys and checking if all the letters in the right column check out (using 7 columns, of course) would significantly speed up the search. Remember the word boundaries. You probably don't want an overabundance of Q's and Z's :)

Comment: You mean that I should create columns using the letters that are ciphered with the same letter of the key?
- letter 1: 1,15,22...
- letter 2: 2,16,23... an so on until letter 7. In that case I will have 7 strings which presumably are ciphered with the same letter of the key. The result is the following 7 strings.
bvisfbctdzrbbybo
ngowynfgrsgnnhnk
myoeumtetebmmnm
khprigyyyfhkhmg
onkcohhjgxuoyky
gimvgjnnvxttuou
tuxdvygxcdggivi

Comment: Yep, then choose a key and see if the result makes sense. Some letters make more sense than others at the start / end of a word, so that's why you need to keep the word boundaries. There is too little ciphertext to do too much with statistics. Just trying keys until finished may make more sense. And try to see words, because if you find a full word then you're done - you would have at least 4 characters of the key (because the smallest word is 4 chars).

Comment: Can you show me how to do it with a practical example? If I create the 7 columns I  will have 7 strings ciphered with the same letter, and as they are not consecutive in the plaintext I won't see if they make sense after I found the correct key letter. My guess is to perform a frequency analysis to the string and try to match that with the english dictionary (as every column is a simple substitution cipher on its own). But I'm afraid that the strings are very short to the frequency analysis to be effective. Thank @MaartenBodewes !

Comment: I can compare the only 4 letter word in the ciphertext with all the 4-letter words in english and see if the result is a part of a 7-letter-word. I have done that with a few common words such as: have, from, with, this, and that. But I should continue in that direction. You're right, the ciphertext is very short to perform frequency analysis. Thanks again! I will let you know how it goes!

Comment: Something interesting that I have discovered is a relationship between the most frequent trigrams in the ciphertext and their distribution in a computer keyboard: they are together, horizontally or vertically. (Please see the image with the trigrams histogram).